# Hibernate: Changing DiscriminatorValue of a subclass throws org.hibernate.WrongClassException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have class **A** with subclasses **B** and **C**.
I am using **InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE** and one column, **type**, is being used as DiscriminatorColumn.

Earlier, class **B** has **DiscriminatorValue("1")** and class **C** has **DiscriminatorValue("2")**.
I have some 100+ entries in the table and all was working fine.

Now, I have created one more subclass of **A**, **D**. But I wanted it to have **DiscriminatorValue("1")**, so I changed DiscriminatorValues of **B** and **C** to 2 and 4 respectively.
I also updated the database column **type** with appropriate values.

But now when I run the application, I am getting following exception:

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 9 was not of the 
specified subclass: com.example.D (Discriminator: 1)
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I figured out the problem. The entry for class D in **persistence.xml** file was missing. Now, its working fine.

Comment: Thank you! Wasted my time on so many other threads about this, and they completely missed this simple point!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was adding some hard-coded values to the database and I wrote "Guest" for discriminator value in insertion queries.

My mistake was that I annotated Guest class to have "guest" (small 'g') as discriminator value, and added guests into database with "Guest" discriminator value.

Good link with a few possible solutions: [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1621)

I really hope that this helps someone.