# Can I subclass a @Entity based on a table column being non-null/non-empty?

Tags: hibernate, single-table-inheritance

I'm using Hibernate4.1 in a Jboss7 environment and a Postgres9 database as the backend. I have one table named `documents`. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
  id serial primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  path varchar(255) not null,
  content text
);
```

Now I already have an entity named `Document` that reflects this table:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  Integer id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  String name;
  String path;
  @Type(type = "text")
  String content;
}
```

The actual table/entity are somewhat bigger and the entity has a bunch of logic attached to it based on whether it is backed by a file (non-empty `path`) or a string only (non-empty `content`). I want to split out the file handling into a separate entity called `FileDocument` that would extend from `Document`. 
Can I map this with Hibernate and if so, how?

I'd prefer if I can express this "naturally" using single table inheritance and based on the `path` column without the need to add another column.

I should probably add that "file-backed" documents still can have a non-empty `content` if the document can be parsed or OCR'ed.

Comment: Did you check the MappedSuperClass annotation?

Comment: Yes, but my understanding was that `@MappedSuperClass` is only for sharing common attributes between entities? In this case, my root `Document` class is a full blown entity that all my current code queries for (but sometimes it will now get a subclass with additional features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been more straightforward then I thought:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorFormula("CASE WHEN path IS NULL OR path = '' THEN 'Document' ELSE 'FileDocument' END")
public class Document {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  Integer id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  String name;
  String path;
  @Type(type = "text")
  String content;
}
```

And in `FileDocument.groovy` (yes, I mix java and groovy entities just fine)

```
@Entity
class FileDocument extends Document {
  def tellMe() {
    "yes, sir!"
  }
}
```

The only stumbling point has been a `WrongClassException` from Hibernate (like in [Hibernate: org.hibernate.WrongClassException, SINGLE_TABLE inheritance and DiscriminatorFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667671/hibernate-org-hibernate-wrongclassexception-single-table-inheritance-and-discr?rq=1)), but that was me mistaking the [Hibernate Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/) which says:

> If you do not set @DiscriminatorValue on a class, the fully qualified
>   class name is used.

So I originally had

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("CASE WHEN path IS NULL OR path = '' THEN 'com.mycompany.entity.Document' ELSE 'com.mycompany.entity.FileDocument' END"
```

Notice the fully qualified class name. However, Hibernate was indexing the subclasses of `Document` with their **unqualified** name and the value returned from the formula therefore didn't match any class definition I provided.